# SMTP : Newline Problem

Tags: c#, smtp

I am sending a string as the message through SMTP. 
But the final mail does not consider the tabs and newlines. 
What might be the problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that you are sending the mail as HTML, in which cases spaces, tabs,  and newlines will all get collapsed down to one space.

You'll need to convert tabs to `&nbsp;` or similar, and replace newlines with `<br>` tags (or wrap paragraphs with `<p>` tags).

Alternately, you can send the mail as plain text, and those characters will be preserved:

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following header:

```
Mime-Type: text/plain
```

This will make most email readers keep the whitespace intact, and most of the time enforce a fixed-width font.

If you're already using HTML mail, then encapsulating everything inside of a `<pre></pre>` should do it. Or, if you're into CSS, you can do `<div style="white-space: pre;">...</div>`.

Also, make sure that what you're sending through the server has `\r\n` (0x0D, 0x0A) line endings and not just `\n` (UNIX) or `\r` (Mac).

Comment: Thanks! I only started getting a fixed-width font (necessary to preserve the formatting of the message) when I switched from using plain text (IsBodyHtml = false) to using HTML (IsBodyHtml = true) and wrapping the body with <pre></pre>, as you suggested.

Comment: I had similar problem, and  tried various combinations I read here on SO and the <pre></pre> suggestion did the trick!  Thanks!